# How to send http request in android?

Tags: java, android

I want the following request format to be send to the rest webservice how can i do so ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<demo>
<headers>
  <messagetype>1</messagetype>
  <messagetoken>123647356734156</messagetoken>
</headers>
<authentication>
  <name>xxx</name>
  <servicename>yyy</servicename>
  <username>10121</username>
  <password>welcome1234</password>
</authentication>
</demo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easiest way is to create a string with XML request value. For the example, you can pass this XML string request value to the below function to fetch response from the server.

FYI, you can pass request by setting entity value inside object of HTTPPost, same way in below example. You can also pass JSON request value this way.

For example:

```
public HttpResponse postData(String strXML) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("web service URL");

    try {
        StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(strXML,HTTP.UTF_8);
        strEntity.setContentType("text/xml");  
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
        httppost.setEntity(strEntity);  // here you can set request value.

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return response;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: then how can i read the response back?

Answer (score 0):

try reslet http://www.restlet.org/ they also have a version for android..